# About polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F[x]$ be a ring of polynomials and $F[x]/f(x)$ denote the polynomial in $F[x]$ having degree less than the degree of $f(x)$. How do we show that if $f(x)$ is irreducible polynomial, then $F[x]/f(x)$  is a field?Here Field F is finite field.  We define a ring structure as.  Addition of two  polynomials in  F[x]/f(x)  is also of degree less than degree of f(x). So closed under addition. Multiplication of  a(x) ,b(x)is defined as:  a(x).b(x) congurent modulo f(x) ie. reminder polynomial when we  divide the a(x).b(x) by f(x). So multiplication is closed. So it make it a ring......

Comment: Your ring is an integral domain, so the principal ideal generated by the an irreducible polynomial is what kind of ideal?

Comment: Your description of $F[x]/f(x)$ is probably not correct. Apart from the fact that it is usually written $F[x]/(f(x))$, we normally use the cosets modulo $f$ as its element, not polynomials of degree less than the degree of $f(x)$; after all, this description would make $F[x]/f(x)$ depend only on $\deg f$, not on $f$ as a whole, and so the irreducibility of $f4 is irrelevant. Finally, if you introduce the quotient like that, you need to define the ringstructure on it separately! - TL;DR There is a reason why we use cosets ...

Comment: Sorry  , i forget to define structure. Now i define a structure on it.

Comment: Yes i agree that the ideal is maximal and hence F[x]/f(x) is field. But  i think here situation is some what different  @ chris Leary

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  now i define a structure on it

Comment: @ChrisLeary  please help me.....

Comment: Since $f$ is irreducible, every polynomial of degree less than the degree of $f$ is relatively prime to $f.$ Let $p$ be such a polynomial. Then there are polynomials $s,t$ in $F[x]$ such that $sp+tf=1,$ 1 being the constant 1 polynomial. When you take the quotient by $(f),$ you get that the coset of $s$ is an inverse for the coset determined by $p.$ That should do it. This is the same argument you would use to show that the ring of integers mod a prime is a field.

Comment: Finally you are defining the ring structure via addition multiplication modulo $f$ so this is same as thinking in terms of cosets of the ideal generated by $f(x) $ in $F[x] $. And then your quotient is a field if the polynomial $f$ is irreducible.